# Pivot table with dynamic column names MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Hello to everyone reading this,

After searching for some time, I realised what I need is a Pivot table. However it needs to be dynamic. At the where clause, I will configure the institution_id and every institution is either a Nursery/Primary School/Secondary School so means that the column name will change as the age is different for every stage of life. (I have to concatenate the age and gender together)

This is the SQL query that I used.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF("2018-08-31", date_of_birth)), "%Y")+0 AS `Age`, class.name AS `Name`,
CASE 
    WHEN gender_id = '1'
           THEN 'M'
           ELSE 'F' 
    END as Gender

from security_users AS `su`
INNER JOIN institution_class_students AS `cs`
ON su.id = cs.student_id

INNER JOIN institution_classes AS `class`
ON cs.institution_class_id = class.id

WHERE cs.institution_id = 538

ORDER BY Name
```

Below is some sample output for one class after running the above query.

```
Age Name      Gender
3   Form 1-1    M
4   Form 1-1    F
4   Form 1-1    F
3   Form 1-1    F
3   Form 1-1    F
4   Form 1-1    M
4   Form 1-1    M
4   Form 1-1    F
5   Form 1-1    F
4   Form 1-1    F
3   Form 1-1    F
3   Form 1-1    F
3   Form 1-1    M
3   Form 1-1    M
4   Form 1-1    F
4   Form 1-1    F
5   Form 1-1    F
5   Form 1-1    F
4   Form 1-1    M
4   Form 1-1    M
```

Based on the output above, the is what my result should look like. If I were to run for an institution with older students, it will be etc 11-M, 11-F, 12-M, 12-F.

```
Class     3-M  3-F  4-M 4-F 5-M 5-F                                     
Form 1-1   3    4    4   6   0   3
```

Below is how it supposed to look if I were to run for an institution

```
Class    3-M  3-F  4-M  4-F 5-M 5-F                                     
Form 1-2  5    6    3    2   0   1   
Form 1-3  4    2    7    5   0   0    
Form 2    0    0    4    1   7   1   
Form 3    0    0    0    0   8   9
```

Will this be possible to do? I have read many of the pivot table tutorial but I have difficulty understanding how to do it. Anyone can shed some light on this. Appreciate every help! Hope the above details is easy to understand.

Comment: It is possible. Can you post the create query for the tables that you used and some sample data? I'll see if I can help

Comment: if possible, create a sqlfiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot -- It contains (and explains) a Stored Procedure that looks at the table in order to build the necessary pivot query.  Then it executes it.  The `CALL` to the stored proc provides 6 arguments, which provides more flexibility than most people need.